# List the contents of a file in DBFS filestore

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

How can I list the contents of a CSV file (under Filestore) in Azure Databricks notebook using the %fs commands ? At least the first few lines like the "head" command in linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list the contents of a file in DBFS filestore, you can use "`dbutils.fs.head`" command.

**Example:** dbutils.fs.head("/foobar/baz.txt")

> dbutils.fs.head("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Batsmen.csv")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

List the contents of a file in DBFS filestore

1. Using Magic Command %fs

   %fs head /Filestore/filename.csv
2. Using DButils directory

   dbutils.fs.head("/Filestore/filename.csv")
3. Using DButils directory and display data in more readble format

   `contents = dbutils.fs.head("/Filestore/filename.csv")` 
   display(contents)